# Matplotlib: How do I have the xtick labels apear on the other side of the x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In this bar chart:

[image]

How do I make the x-axis labels appear in the bars of the bar-chart and left-aligned with the x-axis?

I tried the `ax.xaxis.labelpad()` method but it does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the `y` location of the ticks when you call `set_xticklabels`. So, if you set `y` to something small but positive, it should be placed inside the bars.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.bar([0,1,2,3],[7900,9400,8700,9990],facecolor='#5080B0',edgecolor='k',width=0.3)

ax.set_xticks([0.15,1.15,2.15,3.15])

ax.set_xticklabels(['beek1','beek2','orbath','Kroo'],
                   rotation='vertical',y=0.05,va='bottom')
```

Produces the following plot:

[image]